# find text in html with javascript and return following string

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I'm writing a simple chrome extension that looks for the name of a wordpress theme a page is running. Would it be the easiest to parse for "wp-content/theme" and then return the next word after theme?

Example:

Find - wp-content/theme/

```
<link rel="stylesheet" id="pagelines-pro-css" href="http://example.com/wp-   content/themes/platformpro/"
```

Return text - Plateforpro

Answer (score 1):

Except that themes can be inside subfolders of theme. You gotta watch out for that.

Answer (score 1):

you could get the link with jQuery and check if it is the link with the wordpress theme and then get the last part like this:

```
$('link').each(function() {  
    var href = $(this).attr('href');  
    if (href.indexOf('wp-content/themes') != -1) {  
        if (href.lastIndexOf('/') == href.length - 1) {  
            href = href.substring(0, length- 2);  
        }  
        var theme = href.substring(href.lastIndexOf(/), href.length - 1);  
    }  
}
```

Comment: Except now that the last part might me style.css or similar (especially in wordpress.com).

Comment: So what's wrong? I don't get your comment. Could you explain so I can improve my answer? @dda

Comment: It means that the last part might not be the subfolder where the theme resides, but the css file itself. My advice would be split the string at '/', pop the last element, if it's a file (xxxx.yyy), pop the previous element, and THAT should be the folder. OTOH, if it's not a file, then good.

Comment: that's true, but my answer works for a link as given in the question, so how could I have known? But i'll improved it later today. @dda

Comment: You couldn't know, of course. I happen to have a blog hosted on wordpress.com and it just happens to fall in the /theme/subfolder/coraline/style.css?m=... case.